# Can Neo4j Store BIG DATA

Tags: neo4j, bigdata

I have **200 GB** of csv data from which i want to create a graph database.

My data is pre-processed with Spark, and i know that with Caps([***Cypher-for-Apache-Spark***](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark)) we can create graphs from a data-frame and store it to Neo4j.

so can we store a BIG graph in Neo4j ?

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j has theoretically no limits for data storage. But you have to configure your hardware to get the best from the database. You can have a look at [this](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/) page for more information.

Comment: i can use AWS-servers big storage capacites, without more configuration would that work without problems ?

Comment: Yes you can store your database on AWS servers, and then call back any instance.